# Extract string between delimiter ":" using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a delimiter ":" and need to extract word1 word2 word3 and word4 from below:

```
word1:word2:word3:word4
```

What is the RegEx to extract word1, word2, word3 and word4.

Comment: Hi. What have you tried? If not tried anything, try it out and then ask here if it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean extract? Replace it with commas? Put it in an array? If so, what language?

Comment: You don't need a regex for this. Just a split. Which platform/language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Regex below match any number of words separated by colons:

```
 /([^:]+)/g
```

or match custom number of words

```
/([^:]{min_number,max_number})/g
```

simple way in javascript:

```
 "word:word:word".match( /([^:]+)/g )
```

You will get array:

```
["word","word","word" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Regex will match 4 non-colon words separated by colons:

```
/([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+)/
```

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thats one way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you're using you would most likely be better using a split function.

e.g. in C# you would do.

```
var words = "word1:word2:word3:word4".split(":");
//word[0] = "word1"
//word[1] = "word2"
//ect...
```

Answer (score 0):

he didn't mention any languages. why are you guys keeping asking the language? just because it is a typical "split" case? It could be that he has a long text with that format, and he just want to extract the words with some shell command or text editor.

In this case, a regex solution makes sense.

```
[^:]*(?=:)|(?<=:)[^:]*
```

this would work for the requirement. extract words. test with grep:

```
kent$   echo "word1:word2:word3:word4"|grep -Po '[^:]*(?=:)|(?<=:)[^:]*'
word1
word2
word3
word4
```